# mongodb will drop collection lock database?

Tags: mongodb

I am about to drop a collection with 20M documents, is it gonna lock other inserts on other collections? or lock the database? its about 20GB in size and there is live traffic which inserts on another collection. I am afraid to drop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation it will
"T... obtains a write lock on the affected database and will block other operations until it has completed."

see https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/db.collection.drop/

Comment: I ran on a smaller collection 4GB, but i didnt see any connections on db.currentOP(), so im not sure. also it doesnt get back the space after?

Comment: As I understand, it will not return the memory unless you drop the database. It will use it for other collections.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.drop/) "drop collection" is going to lock whole database until operation complete.
If you want to speed it up, you can drop all indexes one by one, and after that drop collection. In this way it should take less time to complete.

Answering you above question about space - mongodb will not free space used by collection, to do it you should use [repairDatabase](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/). But be very careful, it will block your database for quite long period of time. Also it require at least a lot of free space on disc with db